# Телеграм Бот на Python, который не позволял бы людям подписываться на канал при достижении 1000 подписчиков

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день. С майскими Вас праздниками! Подскажите пожалуйста, вот имеется телеграм бот на Python. Хочу написать скрипт, который бы не позволял людям подписываться на канал (вот сейчас имеется 1000 подписчиков, чтобы другие не имели возможности уже подписаться на канал, то есть вот 1000 подписчиков и всё, больше не будет). Как можно это осуществить? Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])` - поможет отловить нового участника

`bot.get_chat_members_count()` - покажет кол-во участников.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def count_member(message):
    if bot.get_chat_members_count() == 1000:
        # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нас и так много')
        # bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'нас и так много')
    else:
        # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'велкам')
```